# is there any kind of paw/pads lines or paw muscle anatomy in animal hands?

Tags: zoology, anatomy

just like in the title my question is, is there any kind of paw/pads lines or paw muscle anatomy in animal hands? or its pretty much random?

example like mammary lines as bilateral structure that rules where mammary tissue can develop. is there similar thing like this for animal paw/pads? especially comparable to human hands?

prefferably include image (example like this mammary lines) if possible.

[image]

Comment: Do hands have developmental pathways, yes there are a lot of them, listing them all would be pushing it for a single question.

Comment: @John a link is fine too

Comment: try starting here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19553860 and https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1287982-overview

Comment: @John so far as i read and search the link you provide, none of them talk or has anything resemble about paw/pads though, im not talking about the hands generally but specifically about the paw/pads but not exactly about human palm either if its not clear.

Comment: human hands and forepaws are the same thing, there really is no formal distinction.  they are all controlled by the same developmental pathways.